# Filter fast click events in Ubuntu

Tags: 13.10, mouse

In Ubuntu, my mouse double clicks sometimes on a single click event. I have another mouse at work that actually exhibits a similar problem in Windows and I was able to filter the double clicks by using a program called AutoHotKey to intercept the faulty mouse click and throw away clicks that happen in less than 150ms. Is there a way to filter these click events in Ubuntu either natively or using a similar utility? (AutoHotKey is Windows only, and it reportedly does not work with Wine.)

[These](http://leo.steamr.com/2012/08/fixing-mouse-buttonwheel-from-unintended-double-clicking/) are the instructions I followed to fix this using AutoHotKey, just to give an example of how I fixed this in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoKey can do everything you're asking for. You can find it in the Ubuntu Software Centre.